# Setting Javascript Date in future

Tags: javascript

I'm editing a countdown clock but unsure how to set the future date in javascript. The example set's it for the next New Years. I need to set it as a fixed date, 27th April 2015.

```
            // Grab the current date
            var currentDate = new Date();

            // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
            var futureDate  = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);

            // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
            var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
```

I'm just unsure how to set the future date correctly to be the 27 April 2015.

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Did you try `futureDate = new Date(2015, 3, 27)`?

Comment: `new Date(2015, 3, 27)` Note that months start with zero.  There's pretty good documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(27); 
d.setMonth(3); 
d.setYear(2015); 
console.log(d);
```

Comment: That worked - can I ask why the month is 3 for April? I would have naturally thought it should be 4 being the fourth month?

Comment: One more thing. use setFullYear() insetad of setYear(). See more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear

Answer (score 1):

This is how you add days to a date:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
futureDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 10 /* 10 days */ );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just want to set it to April 27th of the next year? If so this should work.

```
var futureDate  = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 3, 27);
```

Working JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kitchenfinks/xukwLbdk/